# My CPU usage in A2 Hosting Shared Plan (Turbo Boost) is high due to mysql query!

Tags: plugins, mysql

Can anyone please let me know that what this query means as it increases my CPU usage to 99 in A2 Hosting Shared Turbo Boost plan. I am using Photo Contest Wordpress plugin from CodeCanyon by Gallery Plugins. I'm using Lite Speed cache plugin too.

`SELECT wpcbv_posts.* FROM wpcbv_posts INNER JOIN wpcbv_postmeta ON ( wpcbv_posts.ID = wpcbv_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wpcbv_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wpcbv_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) INNER JOIN wpcbv_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wpcbv_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wpcbv_postmeta.meta_key = 'contest-photo-points' AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'contest-active' AND mt1.meta_value = '1' ) AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'photo-related-to-contest' AND mt2.meta_value = '35' ) ) ) AND wpcbv_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ((wpcbv_posts.post_status <> 'trash' AND wpcbv_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft')) GROUP BY wpcbv_posts.ID ORDER BY wpcbv_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd guess it's looking for photos in contest 35 in the database, ordered by best photo first. But I don't know exactly what the plugin stores in each meta value.

Comment: If you're having problems with a plugin though you should talk to the authors. Particularly if you've paid for it and have support, as you will have for something you've purchased from CodeCanyon.

Comment: That said you can investigate the poor performance yourself by getting your database to show you the query execution plan and see if there are any table scans it's doing that look wrong. The WordPress meta table model is more or less a key value store and doesn't always perform well, and there are some plugins e.g. Yoast SEO that have moved to tables with specific columns for their needs when they've had problems with meta tables. I can't see that this is doing anything crazy at first glance though - all the tables are joined by post ID which should be indexed.

Comment: the contest photo plugin is using a meta query to find posts, and searching for posts by their meta queries gets very slow when those tables get large. This isn't something that can be fixed easily unless you get rid of that plugin, and you're in a worst case scenario being on shared hosting. _3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope._ You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your query)? for confirmation of index used?